# Looking for a BindingList.AboutToRemove event

Tags: .net

When an item is added to the BindingList, the ListChange event lets me know so I can react accordingly.

However, when an item is ***Removed*** from the list, the ListChange event comes too late, as the item is no longer ***in*** the list. How can you catch the removal ***before*** it has been removed?

I need to identify the object so I can remove an event handler that has been attached to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current implementation of `BindingList<T>` doesn't appear to support this. Your best option may be to create your own implementation of BindingList which has a Removing event:

```
public class MyBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    public event ListChangedEventHandler Removing;

    protected void OnRemoving(ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Removing != null)
        {
            Removing(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        if(index > -1 && index < this.Count)
        {
            OnRemoving(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemDeleted, index));
            base.RemoveItem(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I was able to apply your C# code to my VB application and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

The VB implentation of Rex's C# code.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyBindingList
    Inherits BindingList(Of T)

    Public Event Removing As ListChangedEventHandler

    Protected Overrides Sub RemoveItem(ByVal index As Integer)
        If index > -1 AndAlso index < Me.Count Then
            RaiseEvent Removing(Me, New ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemDeleted, index))
        End If
        MyBase.RemoveItem(index)
    End Sub

End Class
```